# Disable SELinux file read protection for httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, httpd, selinux

I am using RHEL 6.1 and I would like to configure SELinux to authorize httpd to read all files in some folders (My goal is to make log files available via web access).

- Is this possible without listing explicitely all files ?
- Is this possible without disabling SELinux for httpd ?

I need solution which could be made persistent.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a rule to allow `httpd_t` to read the type of file your logfiles are labeled with.

For example, if I want `httpd_t` to be able to read `your_log_file_type_t`, you create a policy module like this (out of the back of my head). Call it apache_read_logs.te and put it in an empty directory:

```
policy_module(apache_read_logs, 1.0)

type httpd_t;
type your_log_file_type_t;
type your_log_dir_type_t;

allow httpd_t your_log_dir_type_t:dir list_dir_perms;
read_files_pattern(httpd_t, your_log_dir_type, your_log_file_type)
read_lnk_files_pattern(httpd_t, your_log_dir_type, your_log_file_type)
```

This allows `httpd_t` to read files labeled `your_log_file_type_t` and search through directories labeled `your_log_dir_type_t`. It uses macros for brevity. You can see how the macros look by downloading and examining the [reference policy tarball](http://oss.tresys.com/projects/refpolicy).

Then, from the directory you created the file in, you run, as root:

```
# make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile
# /usr/sbin/semodule -i apache_read_logs.pp
```

This assumes you have selinux-policy-devel and policycoreutils installed. Test this on a non-crucial machine first! I wrote this blind and haven't tested it myself!

Comment: Quick remark: The apache log files should already be labeled httpd_log_t by default.

Comment: Yes, but nobody said it concerns Apache log files here :)